# Python: Noise RGB 2d array produces columns of colour

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library, noise, perlin-noise

I'm following [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@yvanscher/playing-with-perlin-noise-generating-realistic-archipelagos-b59f004d8401) and had to update it to use PIL's `Image.fromarray` instead of scipy's `toimage`. When I run this code (a small 64^2 rather than a whole 1024^2), the output appears to have columns of contiguous colour. Even in the first code set where I'm supposed to get a nice blobby black and white, it looks like columns of repeating static cubes. 
Why is this?

```
import noise
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

shape       = (64,64)
scale       = 100.0
octaves     = 6
persistence = 0.5
lacunarity  = 2.0

world = np.zeros(shape)
for i in range(shape[0]):
    for j in range(shape[1]):
        world[i][j] = noise.pnoise2(j/scale, 
                                    i/scale, 
                                    octaves     = octaves, 
                                    persistence = persistence, 
                                    lacunarity  = lacunarity, 
                                    repeatx     = 1024, 
                                    repeaty     = 1024, 
                                    base        = 0)


blue = [65,105,225]
green = [34,139,34]
beach = [238, 214, 175]

def add_color(arr):
    color_world = np.zeros(arr.shape+(3,))
    for i in range(shape[0]):
        for j in range(shape[1]):
            if arr[i][j] < -0.05:
                color_world[i][j] = blue
            elif arr[i][j] < 0:
                color_world[i][j] = beach
            elif arr[i][j] < 1.0:
                color_world[i][j] = green

    return color_world

color_world = add_color(world)

im = Image.fromarray(color_world, "RGB")
im.show()
```

[image: RGB 2D Perlin Noise Array]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `PIL.Image.fromarray` expects its argument to be an array of integer values, but Numpy defaults to creating arrays of floating-point values.  So your `color_world` array contains floating-point values, and therefore your image is mangled.  The vertical banding happens because of similarities in the binary representation of those floating-point values.

To fix, use the Numpy array's `astype` method to force the `Image.fromarray` argument to be an array of `uint8`, because that's the appropriate size for your R, G and B components.  Instead of:

```
im = Image.fromarray(color_world, "RGB")
```

do:

```
im = Image.fromarray(color_world.astype("uint8"), "RGB")
```

Alternatively, create `color_world` as an array of `uint8` right from the beginning.  To do that, change:

```
    color_world = np.zeros(arr.shape+(3,))
```

to:

```
    color_world = np.zeros(arr.shape+(3,), dtype="uint8")
```

This might be slightly more efficient.